# Angular 2 - View not updating after model changes

Tags: angular

I have a simple component which calls a REST api every few seconds and receives back some JSON data.  I can see from my log statements and the network traffic that the JSON data being returned is changing, and my model is being updated, however, the view isn't changing.

My component looks like:

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RecentDetectionService} from '../services/recentdetection.service';
import {RecentDetection} from '../model/recentdetection';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'recent-detections',
    templateUrl: '/app/components/recentdetection.template.html',
    providers: [RecentDetectionService]
})



export class RecentDetectionComponent implements OnInit {

    recentDetections: Array<RecentDetection>;

    constructor(private recentDetectionService: RecentDetectionService) {
        this.recentDetections = new Array<RecentDetection>();
    }

    getRecentDetections(): void {
        this.recentDetectionService.getJsonFromApi()
            .subscribe(recent => { this.recentDetections = recent;
             console.log(this.recentDetections[0].macAddress) });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getRecentDetections();
        let timer = Observable.timer(2000, 5000);
        timer.subscribe(() => this.getRecentDetections());
    }
}
```

And my view looks like:

```ts
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Recently detected</h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Recently detected devices</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Table -->
    <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed;  word-wrap: break-word;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Vendor</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Mac</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  >
            <tr *ngFor="#detected of recentDetections">
                <td>{{detected.broadcastId}}</td>
                <td>{{detected.vendor}}</td>
                <td>{{detected.timeStamp | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                <td>{{detected.macAddress}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I can see from the results of `console.log(this.recentDetections[0].macAddress)` that the recentDetections object is being updated, but the table in the view never changes unless I reload the page.

I'm struggling to see what I'm doing wrong here.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I recommend to make code more clean and less complex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48873980/571030

Answer (score 247, accepted):

It might be that the code in your service somehow breaks out of Angular's zone. This breaks change detection. This should work:

```ts
import {Component, OnInit, NgZone} from 'angular2/core';

export class RecentDetectionComponent implements OnInit {

    recentDetections: Array<RecentDetection>;

    constructor(private zone:NgZone, // <== added
        private recentDetectionService: RecentDetectionService) {
        this.recentDetections = new Array<RecentDetection>();
    }

    getRecentDetections(): void {
        this.recentDetectionService.getJsonFromApi()
            .subscribe(recent => { 
                 this.zone.run(() => { // <== added
                     this.recentDetections = recent;
                     console.log(this.recentDetections[0].macAddress) 
                 });
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getRecentDetections();
        let timer = Observable.timer(2000, 5000);
        timer.subscribe(() => this.getRecentDetections());
    }
}
```

For other ways to invoke change detection see [Triggering change detection manually in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)

Alternative ways to invoke change detection are

```ts
ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
```

to immediately run change detection for the current component and its children

```ts
ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()
```

to include the current component the next time Angular runs change detection

```ts
ApplicationRef.tick()
```

to run change detection for the whole application

Comment: Another alternative is to inject ChangeDetectorRef and call `cdRef.detectChanges()` instead of `zone.run()`.  This could be more efficient, since it will not run change detection over the entire component tree like `zone.run()` does.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I guess if you just change instance members this might be more efficient. What do you think about code that executes for example `this.router.navigate()` (with lots of side effects in other components) in code that runs outside Angulars zone. I think here `detectChanges()` might not fix the issue. What do you think?

Comment: Agree.  Only use `detectChanges()` if any changes you make are local to the component and its descendants.  My understanding is that `detectChanges()` will check the component and its descendants, but `zone.run()` and `ApplicationRef.tick()` will check the entire component tree.

Comment: This wasn't the issue (the real issue was a missing @Input annotation) but it's a good suggestion. I've seen quite a few questions on here where change detection was the issue.

Comment: Missing input where? For what field?

Comment: The `recentDetections` field in the component

Comment: @John seems to be a very smart guy :) I can't see haw `@Input()` is related to your code even after having pointed it out. You get the value from a service. `this.recentDetections = recent;` how is `@Input()` related?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm hoping @John can explain it, because it definitely fixes the issue.

Comment: Input is to pass values into the component like `<recent-detections [recentDetections]="someValuesFromParent">`

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.. using `@Input()` didn't make sense nor worked.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you explain why this is needed?  What about this code forces us to explicitly call `zone.run`?  Is it because the `timer` event doesn't force change detection?

Comment: zone.js patches async APIs to get notified when they were called to run change detection afterwards. Usually when change detection isn't run (view is only updated when clicked on some button or similar) this indicates that some Angular code was called from a callback that is not covered by zone.js. I guess `Observable.timer()` is working fine now and this was some bug back then. Do you have this issue with `Observable.timer()` with recent versions of Angular2?

Comment: I'm still having this problem. We're using zone.run in every place we're updating a view from an observable. How do you use the async pipe with a zone.run, or is there an updated answer to this question?

Comment: Usually there is no need to use `zone.run`. With rxhs the issues should be fixed. Some APIs and 3rd party libraries are not fully supported but that should definitely be the exception. Can you reproduce your problem in a Plunker?

Comment: I really don't understand why we need all this manual stuff or why angular2 gods left such necessary.  Why doesn't @Input mean that component really really is dependent on whatever the parent component said that depended on in its changing data?  It seems extremely inelegant that it doesn't just work.  What am I missing?

Comment: Worked for me. But this is another example why I have the feeling angular framework developers are lost in the complexity of the angular framework. When using angular as an application developer you have to spent so much time to understand how angular does this or does that and how to workaround things like questioned above. Terrrible!!

Comment: getting error `this.zone.run()` is not a function , any idea ?

Comment: Hi @PardeepJain  What is `this.zone`? I'd need to see more code. Can you try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Unable to reproduce on stackblitz, but `this.zone` in my case is instance which i decalre in constructor, just same like your did in your example.

Comment: Then it's probably not related to the code. There has to be some other issue. Hard to tell without a reproduction.

Comment: thanks your post help me fix my problem on cordova google maps plugin. when map was on focus the component stop to update values. using the NgZone that solve me the problem to bind realtime values....

Answer (score 46):

It is originally an answer in the comments from @Mark Rajcok, But I want to place it here as a tested and worked as a solution using [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) , I see a good point here:

> Another alternative is to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call
> `cdRef.detectChanges()` instead of `zone.run()`. This could be more
> efficient, since it will not run change detection over the entire
> component tree like `zone.run()` does. – Mark Rajcok

So code must be like:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from 'angular2/core';

export class RecentDetectionComponent implements OnInit {

    recentDetections: Array<RecentDetection>;

    constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, // <== added
                private recentDetectionService: RecentDetectionService) {
        this.recentDetections = new Array<RecentDetection>();
    }

    getRecentDetections(): void {
        this.recentDetectionService.getJsonFromApi()
            .subscribe(recent => {
                this.recentDetections = recent;
                console.log(this.recentDetections[0].macAddress);
                this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // <== added
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getRecentDetections();
        let timer = Observable.timer(2000, 5000);
        timer.subscribe(() => this.getRecentDetections());
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
Using `.detectChanges()` inside subscibe could lead to issue [Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849453/attempt-to-use-a-destroyed-view-detectchanges)

To solve it you need to `unsubscribe` before you destroy the component, so the full code will be like:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy} from 'angular2/core';

export class RecentDetectionComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    recentDetections: Array<RecentDetection>;
    private timerObserver: Subscription;

    constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, // <== added
                private recentDetectionService: RecentDetectionService) {
        this.recentDetections = new Array<RecentDetection>();
    }

    getRecentDetections(): void {
        this.recentDetectionService.getJsonFromApi()
            .subscribe(recent => {
                this.recentDetections = recent;
                console.log(this.recentDetections[0].macAddress);
                this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // <== added
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getRecentDetections();
        let timer = Observable.timer(2000, 5000);
        this.timerObserver = timer.subscribe(() => this.getRecentDetections());
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.timerObserver.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

Comment: this.cdRef.detectChanges(); fixed my problem. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but after multiple attempts of call I get error: failure:Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
For me zone.run() helps me come out of this error.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question but I wanted to share my situation. I work on a team and someone set the change detection strategy to be onPush basically disabling automatic change detection. Not sure if this helps anyway else but just in case

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a very similar problem. I was updating my view inside a function that was being called by a parent component, and in my parent component I forgot to use @ViewChild(NameOfMyChieldComponent). I lost at least 3 hours just for this stupid mistake. 
i.e: **I didn't need to use** any of those methods:

- ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
- ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()
- ApplicationRef.tick()

Comment: can you explain how you got your child component updated with @ViewChild? thanks

Comment: I suspect, parent was calling a method of a child class that wasn't rendered, and existed only in memory

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with zones and change detection — let AsyncPipe handle complexity. This will put observable subscription, unsubscription (to prevent memory leaks) and changes detection on Angular shoulders.

Change your class to make an observable, that will emit results of new requests:

```
export class RecentDetectionComponent implements OnInit {

    recentDetections$: Observable<Array<RecentDetection>>;

    constructor(private recentDetectionService: RecentDetectionService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.recentDetections$ = Observable.interval(5000)
            .exhaustMap(() => this.recentDetectionService.getJsonFromApi())
            .do(recent => console.log(recent[0].macAddress));
    }
}
```

And update your view to use AsyncPipe:

```
<tr *ngFor="let detected of recentDetections$ | async">
    ...
</tr>
```

Want to add, that it's better to make a service with a method that will take `interval` argument, and:

- create new requests (by using `exhaustMap` like in code above);
- handle requests errors;
- stop browser from making new requests while offline.