# How can I redraw html after event occurs

Tags: angular

When I change a selection from combobox, variable "steps" will change and that makes the html change like the following.

```
<component-item *ngFor="let step of steps ; let i = index" title={{step.title}} ></component-item>
```

but when "steps" variable changes by event trigger, I get error message.
Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

I tried detach and detectchanges but still I get this message. How can I redraw the html?

Comment: This probably isn't a problem with the code you've shown. Have you taken a look through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849453/attempt-to-use-a-destroyed-view-detectchanges)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because you show only a part of your code, but it looks like the component is being destroyed but you have not unsubscribed from the observable.

Try to implement `OnDestroy` in your component and add a function

```
ngOnDestroy(){
//unsubscribe from your observable for instance if you subscription is called "subs"
this.subs.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: @user3289230, could you mark the answer as accepted if you found it useful ? It would  be very much appreciated ;) .