# Debug change detector

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I ran into this very known Angular issue, where my view is not updating when the data model changes.

My problem is that previously it actually worked, but I can't figure out what change in my code caused it to stop working.

I know there are a some good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919459/4610489) for fixing these kind of issues. But they all seem to me like work arounds, that just make it work without a deep understanding of the problem cause.

My questions then are:

Is there any way to **debug** this kind of issue **properly**?

Can anyone explain how the `Change Detector` works and give clear rules for when the change detection should and shouldn't work?

Comment: Can you provide more information about error problem?

Comment: The point of the question is generally how to debug these kind of issues, not solve my specific problem...

Comment: Open browser put breakpoint and debug it

Comment: Which version angular are you using?

Comment: Yes I know, I debug, I see my data change, but the view is not updating. What next?

Comment: First you need to check current zone by writing `console.log(Zone.current.name)`