# Dynamically inserted value from google api into object not showing up in view

Tags: angular, google-api, ionic2

I am using google matrix api to get distance and duration in my ionic 2 application.Problem which i am facing is that ,since the google api take some time to load i am able to insert values from google api to javascript  array object only after the page is rendered

- values are getting inserted into array object but not showing up in view
- if i interact with UI lets just say press a button or a drop down then inserted values from google api appears

please suggest what might be correct way to tackle this problem ,any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It could be related to Angular's `Change Detector` see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919399/angular-2-view-not-updating-after-model-changes/36919459#36919459

Comment: thanks @naomi you are right , zone.run() method resolved it for me.

Comment: @naomi would you like to add that as an answer so we can close this question?

Comment: @sebaferreras I added my answer, thanks

Comment: @Abhijeet please accept naomi's answer

Comment: sure @naomi, accepted your answer but already had figured it out by myself  few minutes before your comment anyways thanks for the link ,appreciate it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when the view is not updated with data changes, it means something broke out of Angular's zone.

When your code runs outside of the Angular zone, the `Change Detector` could not detect the changes, and the view will not update.

To force change detection - you should explicitly run your code inside the Angular zone using the `zone.run()` method ([docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html)).

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919459/4610489) for more options how to force change detection.