# NG2 - Input from original component is not updating after original value changes

Tags: binding, angular2-template, angular2-changedetection

I am trying to use NG2 binding but for some reason it doesnt work when i have multiple nested @Input data
I have read and tried solutions from:
[Angular 2 - View not updating after model changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919399/angular-2-view-not-updating-after-model-changes)

but without luck.
What I basically have is 3 components (parent -> child -> grandson)
the parent has a data field, the child and the grandson take it as input.
the original value passes without a problem
but when i try to update this value in the parent component, the child and grandson arent updated.

it is in the spirit of the following simple components:

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'parent',  
 template: '<button (click)="updateData()">
             <child [data]="data"></child>'
 })

 export class ChildComponent {  var data = { a : 0};
     click() { this.data.a+=1; }     
 }

 @Component({
 selector: 'child',  
 template: '<grand [data]="data"></grand>' })

 export class GrandComponent {  
     @Input data:any;     
 }

 @Component({
 selector: 'grand',  
 template: '<div>{{data.a}}</div>' })

 export class ParentComponent {  
     @Input data:any;     
 }
```

Comment: There is an answer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831259/how-to-update-child-components-after-receiving-data-from-an-ajax-call-in-parent