# update view after a service data changes

Tags: angular

I've created a simple service `texts-data.service.ts`

```
selectedTextNumber:number = 1;
  constructor() {
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.selectedTextNumber = 0;
      console.log("chans: "+this.selectedTextNumber);

    },2000);
}
  getCurrentTextNumber(){
    return this.selectedTextNumber;
  }
```

I use it in other components: `other.component.ts`

```
    import { TextsDataService } from "../../services/texts-data.service";
    export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {

    fontName:string;

    constructor(public textsDataService: TextsDataService) {
    this.selectedTextNumber = textsDataService.getCurrentTextNumber();
    let currentFont = textsDataService.allTexts[this.selectedTextNumber];
    this.fontName = currentFont.fontName;
    }
```

I am interested in updating the view, once the services data changes. In my case, it changes after 2 seconds, but the view never gets updated. How do I make it refresh itself?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" value="{{fontName}}">
```

Comment: Show your html so we can see how you're updating your view.

Comment: You can probably inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` and call its [detectChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges) method after the data change.

Comment: i've added the html. Basically I just use {{}}.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use a behavior subject. a behavior subject can both watch for updates and subscribe to the data stream. you would import the `'rxjs/BehaviorSubject"` and make a variable that is a new behavior subject, then you would set the value of that behavior subject to the data stream.

you can see a realtime implementation [here](https://namitamalik.github.io/Realtime-Update-in-Angular2/)

and you can see the docs on rxjs behavior subjects [there](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html)

Answer (score 1):

To update the view from the service you have to call the service again.

But also, your HTML doesn't have NgModel, so it won't update anything via that button.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to poll the service from Component class itself. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919399/angular-2-view-not-updating-after-model-changes) there is a very good example that I am sure will help you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to make the selectedTextNumber a getter.

You don't show the declaration of `selectedTextNumber` in your code snippet, but replace that declaration with this:

```
get selectedTextNumber(): number {
    return this.textsDataService.getCurrentTextNumber();
}
```

That way it will re-obtain the value from the service every time it changes.