# When changing value of @Input directive inside a subscribe block in parent, changes are not detected in child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am changing the value for one Input directive to my child component from parent component inside subscribe block. However, the new values are not detected in the child.

The child component already implements `OnChanges` and correctly defines Input directives.

Below is the pseudo code for my components. It is simplified from actual 
code for ease of understanding the context.

PARENT COMPONENT HTML:

```
<h1>PARENT</h1>
<button (click)="buttonClicked()">NEXT</button>
<child-component  [inputChildVar]="parentValue"></child-component>
```

PARENT COMPONENT TS:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.parentValue= {
      "currentPageNo":5,
      "currentPageData": [{"DEVICE":"Kernel1","RANGE":"500Hz"}, {"DEVICE":"Kernel2","RANGE":"500Hz"}]
    }
}

buttonClicked()
{
  this.parentService.ServiceMethod().subscribe(data=>{
     this.parentValue= {
        "currentPageNo":data.currentPageNo,
        "currentPageData":data.array
      }
     this.parentValue=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parentValue))
  })
}
```

CHILD COMPONENT HTML:

```
<h1>inputChildVar<h1>
```

CHILD COMPONENT TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ 
    selector: 'child-component', 
    template: '<h1>inputChildVar<h1>', 
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges 
{ 
    @Input() inputChildVar

    constructor() { } 
    ngOnChanges(){ 
        console.log(this.inputChildVar) 
    } 

    ngOnInit() {} 
}
```

Expected Result: On getting a response from parentService.ServiceMethod, when parentValue is changed, the new values should be reflected on screen through child component.

Actual Result: There is no change on the screen

Comment: Can you put the child component's code?

Comment: import { Component, OnInit, Input,OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<h1>inputChildVar<h1>',
   })
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {

  @Input() inputChildVar
  

  constructor() { }
ngOnChanges(){
  console.log(this.inputChildVar)

}

  ngOnInit() {}

  

}

Comment: @AnkitaS Can you provide StackBlitz?

Comment: @AnkitaS Check out this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4lty84-cb9o5i is this what you wanted?

Comment: I am trying to modify the value in a subscribe block in the parent component. So you need to call any service method and subscribe to the observable response. Inside the subscribe block you need to modify value.

Comment: @AnkitaS Show the code for Service!

Comment: @AnkitaS Have a look at posted answer!

Answer (score 0):

As I tested in the StackBlitz it is working fine for me, have a look at:

`Parent Component HTML`:

```
<h1>PARENT</h1>
<button (click)="buttonClicked()">NEXT</button>
<app-child  [inputChildVar]="parentValue"></app-child>
```

`Parent Component TS`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-overview-example.css'],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {

  constructor(private service: DataService) {

  }
  parentValue = {
    "userId": 112,
    "id": 1121,
    "title": "masxsat",
    "body": "teasdas"
  }
  buttonClicked() {
    this.service.getData()
    this.service.data.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value)
      this.parentValue = value;
    })
  }
}
```

`Child Component HTML`:

```
<h1>Child</h1>
<div>
{{inputChildVar | json}}
</div>
```

`Child Component TS`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() inputChildVar

  constructor() { }
  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.inputChildVar)
  }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

`Data.Service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  data = new BehaviorSubject(null)

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }


  getData() {
    this.get()
      .then(response => {
        this.data.next(response);
      })
  }

  get(): Promise<any> {
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  // handler for error in URL
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4lty84-bhvbsp)

Comment: In my code i am consuming an actual REST API, its not working. I am still not sure what is the issue.

Comment: This is also an API, I would request to check the console is there any error? Or you can paste the real code here if possible!

Comment: There is no error on console. I was able to resolve the issue by triggering change detection through changeDetectorRef. Its working now. Got reference from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919399/angular-2-view-not-updating-after-model-changes

Comment: Ok.. no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by triggering change detection through changeDetectorRef. Its working now. Got reference from : [Angular 2 - View not updating after model changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919399/angular-2-view-not-updating-after-model-changes)