# How to render the cart array in my component as the template interpolation is not working

Tags: angular

I am making a dummy online shopping site.When i add products to the cart the cart array gets updated as i observed in the console but the view is not getting rendered

Here is my view

[cart.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDhgH.png)

Here is my component
[cart-component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4CEt.png)

Comment: You have mixed up a component and a service. please have a look at the tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919399/angular-2-view-not-updating-after-model-changes