# Angular ngModel inside ngFor, with pipe and map, not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm having problems in this situation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    {{items | async| json}}

    <div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      <input type=checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.b"/>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  items = of([{
    name: '1',
  },
  {
    name: '2',
  },
  {
    name: '3',
  }])
  .pipe(map(i=>{
    return i.map(i=>{
      return {
        i: i,
        b: false
      }
    })
  }))
}
```

[Stackblitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-problem)

The problem is that the ngModel is not working and I can't see the b property change.
If I remove the map pipe and I put the boolean property in the first array, all is working.
Am I missing something? What's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-problem-k9p24r?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It’s unclear what you are trying to achieve here..? Why the observable?

Comment: I'm using the observable because this is only a simple example.
In my real application I have an observable as a response from an http call and I need to add some properties (a selected boolean property) to the response before to show on the template

Comment: @PavanShukla, thanks for your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. If you render out `{{item.b}}` in the `ngFor` you will see the value is changing between `true` and `false` correctly. As mentioned in the other answer this is because of references and change detection. You can also simply save the observable data a property on your class using `ngOnInit` and `subscribe`:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    {{ items | json }}

    <form #myForm="ngForm">
      <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        <input [name]="item.i.name" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.b" />
      </div>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData().subscribe(data => (this.items = data));
  }

  private getData() {
    return of([
      {
        name: "1"
      },
      {
        name: "2"
      },
      {
        name: "3"
      }
    ]).pipe(
      map(i => {
        return i.map(i => {
          return {
            i: i,
            b: false
          };
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-problem-v7npzr) in action. Don't forget to clean up any observables if needed to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for all the answer.
Just to understand better, is it possible to maintain only the observable items? I mean, is there a way to trigger the change detection?

Comment: @DavideC There are a few ways to approach this. I'd recommend to look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919399/angular-2-view-not-updating-after-model-changes

Answer (score 2):

Actually what you are doing is correct. 
To check what I mean change your code to this:

```
<input type=checkbox (change)="change(item)" [(ngModel)]="item.b"/>

change(item) {
 console.log(item);
}
```

This is not reflecting on the dom because the items array is mapped to the same memory location and changing an element inside it won't cause a change detection in angular to trigger a display change.