Values not updating after event emit
I've a simple PrimeNg dropdown in a component which shows some items.
topnavbar.component.html
<my-dropdown
  [products]="productItems"
  [tables]="tableItems"
></my-dropdown>

tableItems and productItems are arrays that gets their values from an API call:
topnavbar.component.ts
  getMyList = (params1: string, params2: string) => {
    this.someService
      .getNavList(params1, params2)
      .subscribe({
        next: (resp) => {
          resp.data[0].forEach((item: any) => {
            this.tableItems.push({
              name: item.name,
              url: item.url,
            });
          });
        },
        error: (HttpResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {},
      });
  };

  constructor(
    ...
    private _eventEmitter: RouteEventEmitService
  ) {
    this._eventEmitter.getTableNameEmitter.subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('data', data);
      this.tableItems = [];

      data.data[0].levels.forEach((item: any) => {
        this.tableItems.push({
          name: item.name,
          url: item.url,
        });
      });
    });
  }

In some other component i make a button click and fetch new list and pass on the new list view emit to this topnavbar component.
sidenavigation.component.ts
  buttonClicked = (params: any, params1: string) => {
    this.sidenavService
      .myMethod(params, params11)
      .subscribe({
        next: (resp) => {
          this._eventEmitter.getTableNameEmitter.emit(resp);
        },
        error: (HttpResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {},
      });
  };

Even then i still see the old list. Why the list is not updated. The event emitter is sending the updated list i verfied. Please help.

Does your console log in the constructor log the data when you change it via button click?

Any chance that this is related to change detection? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919399

After the loop that calls this.tableItems.push({...}) in each iteration, do this.tableItems = [...this.tableItems]

If comment from @BennyHalperin won't help, could you make a minimal demo on stackblitz.com? If your console.log('data', data); shows the correct data, then you might need to re-pack the array, because wen you use push, it doesn't see the changes.

Don’t use this.tableItems.push (it’s not triggrer @Input change), try use this:
this.tableItems = […this.tableItems, {
                    name: item.name,
                    url: item.url,
                  });

